# How to show modal window on marker click?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using leafletjs to build a web map and trying to figure out **how to show a modal window when a marker is clicked** (instead of the default popup method).

Here's my setup:

```
var myAirports = L.geoJson(myData, {
        pointToLayer: function(latlng){
            ..snip..
        },
        onEachFeature: function(feature,layer){
            $('#myModalOne').modal(options);
        }
});

myAirports.addTo(map);
```

My HTML is like so:

```
<div id="myModalOne">....</div>
<div id="myModalTwo">....</div>
```

Lets say my data has a featurecollection with a key of 'name' (i.e., 'name': 'Bush Airport') for each feature. Would I just add a switch statement to my onEachFeature function?

Just need a little guidance,thanks.

*Note: I am using Bootstrap for the modal windows*

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you don't need to set the `pointToLayer` option which is useful if you want to display something else than a marker.

What you need is to catch the `click` event on the markers and display a modal window. There is no popup by default.

```
var myAirports = L.geoJson(myData, {
        onEachFeature: function(feature,layer){
            layer.on('click', function(e){
                $('#myModal'+feature.properties.name).modal(options);
                // or whatever that opens the right modal window
            });
        }
});

myAirports.addTo(map);
```